# All possible values of $|ab|$ when $a$ and $b$ commute.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have been trying to solve the following problem from A. R. Wadsworth's *Problems in Abstract Algebra*:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements of finite order in a group $G$, say $|a| = m$ and $|b| = n$. **If $ab = ba$, determine all possible values of $|ab|$.** (Clearly, $|ab| \mid mn$; also, if $\gcd(n, m) = 1$, prove that $|ab| = mn$. But, in general, there can be multiple possibilities for $|ab|$, and which ones occur depend on the prime factorization of $m$ and $n$. For example, if $m = 12$ and $n = 36$, then $|ab| = 9, 18$, or $36$, and all these possibilities do occur.)

The main things I know so far are:
$$
\left. \frac{|a||b|}{|(a) \cap (b)| \cdot \gcd(|a|, |b|)}
  \ \middle| \ |ab| \right.  \quad \text{and} \quad
\left. |ab| \ \middle| \ \frac{|a||b|}{|(a) \cap (b)|} \right.
$$
For the extreme case where $|(a) \cap (b)| = \gcd(|a|, |b|)$, this yields:
$$
\left. \frac{|a||b|}{\gcd(|a|, |b|)^2}
  \ \middle| \ |ab| \right.  \quad \text{and} \quad
\left. |ab| \ \middle| \ \frac{|a||b|}{\gcd(|a|, |b|)} \right.
$$

However, in the example given by Wadsworth, these conditions are obviously not discriminatory enough.

I also noticed that in some extreme case where $G = \langle g \rangle$ and $|g| = |a|\cdot|b|$, we can set $a = g^{|b|}$ and $b = g^{|a|}$, so that
$$
\left|(ab)^i\right| = \left|g^{|a| + |b|}\right| =
\frac{|a||b|}{\gcd(|a||b|, |a| + |b|)}
$$
In the example that Wadswarth gave, the condition that $|ab|$ must be a multiple of this expression seems to work. However, I have not been able to prove this.

---

How does one solve this problem? I am looking for hints, intrusctions, solutions... Any help is appreciated.